# Java date parse

Tags: java, date

I'm attempting to parse the following string into a date object: 9/14/2012 9:50:56 PM

I'm using the following format:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss a");
formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
```

But I keep getting the following date: Fri Sep 14 06:50:56 PDT 2012

I seem to be off by 12 hours (after accounting for the time change).  However when I parse the following string: 9/14/2012 1:00:00 AM - I get the right date object: Thu Sep 13 22:00:00 PDT 2012

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Both answers seem to give the same Date relative to the input date String. I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: Both dates are have a 3 hour difference  9:50:56pm -> 6:50:56pm = 3 hours. 22:00:00 -> 1:00:00 = 3 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your date is in am/pm format, you should use `hh`, instead of `HH` for hours. See the reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

What happens here is the `9` is treated as 09 hours in 24 hour format, which is 9 am, so your date is correctly pushed back 3 hours to make it 6 am. With the second date 1 am is 01 hours, and the date is correct.